# how to give my docusign connect url to connect to SAP server

Tags: docusignapi

To get auto notifications, I am using docusign connect.

I want to save my recipient status in my SAP server.when I give my SAP url it is not connecting it is giving a error could not connect.

How to give my docusign connect url to connect to my backend SAP server.please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can set the DocuSign Connect endpoint (ie. your custom URL that DocuSign pushes to) through the `Connect` page of your Console preferences.  You might have to switch to the old UI to access as I don't believe this is expose through the new Console as of today.

With regards to it error'ing out when you supply your SAP URL - the URL needs to use `https` and it needs to be a publicly available endpoint so that DocuSign can reach it.  If it's a local host or other address that DocuSign can't see then you will get the generic error you are seeing.

Another thing to help debug is if you go to your Console preferences -> Connect, then select the relevant configuration, and take a look at the **Failure logs**.  They should show more info as to why the last Connect push failed.